# Can't type polish letters in Adobe Reader forms

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I can paste them, but can't type. Any ideas? Input method set to X. Same setting works in any text editor.

Comment: My guess is, that Adobe Reader for Linux uses ancient toolkit versions, because it hasn't been supported in years.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the fonts (This happens frequently with Microsoft fonts like Arial,Bold or Arial,Narrow.). You can try installing microsoft fonts:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then edit the startup file:

```
sudo gedit /opt/Adobe/Reader8/bin/acroread
```

And change

```
# Enable this if you donot want Adobe Reader to cache Font-config fonts 
# ACRO_DISABLE_FONT_CONFIG=1
# export ACRO_DISABLE_FONT_CONFIG
```

To

```
# Enable this if you donot want Adobe Reader to cache Font-config fonts
ACRO_DISABLE_FONT_CONFIG=1
export ACRO_DISABLE_FONT_CONFIG
```

Please let me know if this solution works for you.

Comment: Sadly this didn't help. Font used in forms is probably Myriad Pro. It's in properties -> fonts. And I think there is no problem with font, because pasted letters looks ok.